# How to Migrate Oracle 11g R2 (Windows) database to Oracle 12c R2 (Linux) db

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, linux, migration, oracle-12c, windows-server

I have a requirement to migrate Oracle 11g R2 database (Windows platform) to Oracle 12c R2 database (Red Hat Linux platform).

Is there any methods using RMAN to do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Source:

```
RMAN> shutdown immediate
RMAN> startup mount
RMAN> backup database ...
```

Destination:

```
RMAN> startup nomount
RMAN> restore controlfile from ...
RMAN> alter database mount;
RMAN> restore database;
RMAN> alter database open resetlogs upgrade;
```

Then manually upgrade the database to 12.2:

[Example of Manual Upgrade of Windows Non-CDB Oracle Database 11.2.0.3](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/example-manual-upgrade-windows-non-cdb-11203-to-122.html#GUID-30F3DC9C-141A-47DC-9B83-6D0C395E565C)